# Blazorserver timeout

Tags: .net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

Look at this blazor-server code:

```
@page "/test"

<button @onclick="@(() => on_btn_click())">Click me</button>

@code{
    
    private async void on_btn_click()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
           // insert/update/delete query
           bdd.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

- Is there a maximum execution time (timeout) for blazor server functions ?

I am not talking about sql-server timeouts. My queries are not slow but i have to send 10000 queries. (In fact this is not true, this is an example in order to understand the problem). I am talking about C# code execution timeout.

- What happens if user closes the browser and if on_btn_click has not finished ? Does this function continue in a backgroud task ? Or is it killed ?
- Whan happens if user changes page in my blazorserver application and if on_btn_click has not finished ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions depends largely on your application design.

The UI should only contain UI code.  Data code should be in backend services.

Code such as that below doesn't belong in the UI - there's no separation of concerns.

```
        for (int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
           // insert/update/delete query
           bdd.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If you move this code to a scoped service and call it from the UI then the service code will execute independant of the UI and will complete before the server-side Blazor Hub session gets destroyed.

As a singleton service it will always complete unless the web server service is destroyed.

If you want to cancel the action you need to do what @Henk suggests and use cancellation tokens.

Here's a simple working example to demonstrate the service principle:

SlowService

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StackOverflow.Answers.Data
{
    public class SlowService
    {

        public async Task RunToCompletion()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Loop {i}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add as a scoped service to StartUp

Test Page

```
@page "/"
<div> <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick="BtnClick">Start Slow</button></div>

@code {

    [Inject] private StackOverflow.Answers.Data.SlowService slowService { get; set; }

    private async Task BtnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        await slowService.RunToCompletion();
    }
}
```

Now start in debug mode and then duplicate the page.  Click on the button in the duplicate page and then close the page.  Watch the output in the debugger continue logging the loop.